# remove all HTML Tags from a xmlNode

Tags: c#, xmlnode

I have a xml Node as :

```
<description>
<p>Results of a national survey of 18-35 year old Americans revealed that the next generation of homebuyers are more knowledgeable, responsible and savvy.</p> <p>The Better Homes and Gardens Real Estate survey showed that the housing market positively impacted Generation X and Y, which accounts for an estimated 103 million Americans. Seventy-seven percent of the Generation X and Y Americans who were surveyed reported that they have become increasingly knowledgeable about homeownership as a result of increased media coverage that has highlighted real estate topics over the past six years.</p> <p>&quot;Every generation faces defining economic events that alter their collective perspective,&quot; said Sherry Chris, president and CEO of Better Homes and Gardens Real Estate LLC. &quot;&#39;The Greatest Generation&#39; was shaped by the Great Depression and Baby Boomers were impacted by the oil crises throughout the 1970s. Gen X and Gen Y experienced their &#39;coming of age&#39; moment during the largest housing market downturn in American history.&quot;</p> <p>According to the survey, the two younger generations of potential homebuyers aren&#39;t discouraged from buying homes as a result of the financial turmoil the country has went through in the past several years. The two generations reported that they have become more knowledgeable about homeownership not being something they deserve, but it&#39;s something they must earn.</p> <p>The survey also showed that close to all of those surveyed were willing to adjust their lifestyles in order to save up for a home by eating out less, working a second job or even moving back home with their parents.</p> <p>The housing market is on the rise, despite President Obama&#39;s claims that congressional Republicans have held up legislation proposed to lower lending rates for millions of borrowers.</p>
</description>
```

I want to remove all the html tags. I just want is as a plain text.

**NOTE** I want ot use this xml as rssFeeds but google reader  show all the tags as `<p>` as text not as HTML **any IEDA WHY?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your `HTML` show formatted in Google reader you should place: `<![CDATA[ ]]>` around the text inside the `desription`.

```
   <description>
         <![CDATA[
                <p>Results of a national survey of 18-35 year old Americans revealed that the next generation of homebuyers are more knowledgeable, responsible and savvy.</p> <p>The Better Homes and Gardens Real Estate survey showed that the housing market positively impacted Generation X and Y, which accounts for an estimated 103 million Americans. Seventy-seven percent of the Generation X and Y Americans who were surveyed reported that they have become increasingly knowledgeable about homeownership as a result of increased media coverage that has highlighted real estate topics over the past six years.</p> <p>&quot;Every generation faces defining economic events that alter their collective perspective,&quot; said Sherry Chris, president and CEO of Better Homes and Gardens Real Estate LLC. &quot;&#39;The Greatest Generation&#39; was shaped by the Great Depression and Baby Boomers were impacted by the oil crises throughout the 1970s. Gen X and Gen Y experienced their &#39;coming of age&#39; moment during the largest housing market downturn in American history.&quot;</p> <p>According to the survey, the two younger generations of potential homebuyers aren&#39;t discouraged from buying homes as a result of the financial turmoil the country has went through in the past several years. The two generations reported that they have become more knowledgeable about homeownership not being something they deserve, but it&#39;s something they must earn.</p> <p>The survey also showed that close to all of those surveyed were willing to adjust their lifestyles in order to save up for a home by eating out less, working a second job or even moving back home with their parents.</p> <p>The housing market is on the rise, despite President Obama&#39;s claims that congressional Republicans have held up legislation proposed to lower lending rates for millions of borrowers.</p>
        ]]>
    </description>
```

**Answer without note**

If you want to  convert `HTML` to `Text`. Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) you can get this as a [NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). You can then use the `ConvertHtml` method the Agility Pack offers you.

```
var plainText = HtmlToText.ConvertHtml(htmlNodeText);
```

Comment: thanks but can you suggest me that why google reader show the <p> as text not as html in my rss feeds

Comment: @L.B Excuse me, the interface has been updated. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Html` inside `xml` can make your xml invalid.

`xml` is `strict`,but `html` is `not strict` cuz `html` can have some tags without a `closing tag` which is an error in `xml`.

If you want to just replace the  tags,you can use `regex` instead of an `html parser`

```
foreach(var elm in doc.Elements(description))
{
elm.Value=Regex.Replace(elm.Value,"<.*?>","");
}

doc.Save();
```

Comment: thanks but can you suggest me that why google reader show the `<p>` as text not as html in my rss feeds

Comment: @Champ maybe becuz they are concerned more about content not on how the data would be represented